# Calling template methods in template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to figure out why some code that I have won't compile and I done a fair bit of reduction an anonymizing to end up with this example:

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
template<typename T>
class a {
public:
  template<bool b>
  T * amem() {
    return NULL;
  }
};

template<typename T>
class b {
public:
  a<T>* ap;

  template <bool b>
  T * m() {
    return ap->amem<b>();
  }
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Depending on the compiler that I use *and the names of the variables* I get different errors.  They are all centered around this line, though:

```
    return ap->amem<b>();
```

Compiling using clang++ [Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)], I get the following message:

```
tmp.cpp:18:26: error: expected expression
      return ap->amem<b>();
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiling using g++ [i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1], I get the following message:

```
tmp.cpp: In member function ‘T* b<T>::m()’:
tmp.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
tmp.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Mysteriously (to me, anyway).  If I change the name of amem to m, I no longer get any errors from g++, but I get the same error from clang++.

I'm sure there is something here that I just don't understand?  Does anyone know what expression clang and gcc are looking for?  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

If this is a compiler bug (seems doubtful), does anyone know any workarounds that don't involve converting amem into a function with a bool parameter (rather than a template)?  I've done this already and I can confirm that this works around the issue, but this is inside a hot loop and the code that is switched on by b is a memory allocation that probably shouldn't be in a hot loop.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Need to add the `template` keyword:

```
return ap->template amem<b>();
```

Please read [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Crazy.  I didn't know about that use of template.  I've used it for types many times, but never for functions.

Answer (score 4):

In the context where you call

```
return ap->amem<b>();
```

the name `amem` is a dependent name: If such a beast indeed refers to a member function template, you need to say so by adding the keyword `template`:

```
return ap->template amem<b>();
```

BTW, note that you **shall not** define `NULL`! If you need a definition of the abomination you should include, e.g., `cstddef`. Best you use just `0` or `nullptr` when using C++ 2011.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I never define NULL in actual code, but I did it here to make the example as self contained as possible.