# Nested template ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates

Nested templates require the usage of `template` keyword, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336693/calling-template-methods-in-template-classes). Here's a concise demonstration that results in a compiler error:

```
template <int T>
struct A {
  template <int U>
  static void b(int x) {
  }
};

template <int T>
void test() {
  A<T>::b<T>(T); // Should be:
  // A<T>::template b<T>(T);
}

int main() {
  test<0>();
}
```

As a challenge, I was trying to think of a program where two possibilities (with or without `template`) are both valid but have two different meanings, but I couldn't wrap my head around the operator overloading business. Is it possible to make `A<T>::b<T>(T);` a valid statement?

Answer (score -1):

If you change your `struct A` for:

```
template <int T>
struct A {
    static const int b = 5;
};
```

Then `A<T>::b<T>(T);` would compile.

- In that case, `A<T>::b` would be 5.
- `T` is 0.
- Thus 5 < 0 is false (0)
- `0 > (0)` is false too;

If you replace the code with something like:

```
auto x = A<T>::b<T>(T);
std::cout << typeid(x).name() << " " << x;
```

You will get:

> bool 0

Thus it was not too hard to modify `A` so that `A<T>::b<T>(T)` is a valid statement.